# Telegram bot: как создать календарь?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

Использую pyTelegramBotAPI. Как создать календарь ( calendar-keyboard ) в Python? Я пробовал использовать этот способ: https://github.com/grcanosa/telegram-calendar-keyboard, но по какой-то причине у меня не получилось это сделать. Приведите пожалуйста пример кода, вызывающего календарь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import logging
from telegram.ext import Updater
from telegram.ext import  CallbackQueryHandler
from telegram.ext import  CommandHandler
from telegram import  ReplyKeyboardRemove


import telegramcalendar


TOKEN = "<ваш токен>"


logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
                    level=logging.INFO)

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def calendar_handler(bot,update):
    update.message.reply_text("Please select a date: ",
                        reply_markup=telegramcalendar.create_calendar())


def inline_handler(bot,update):
    selected,date = telegramcalendar.process_calendar_selection(bot, update)
    if selected:
        bot.send_message(chat_id=update.callback_query.from_user.id,
                        text="You selected %s" % (date.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")),
                        reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove())



up = Updater(TOKEN)

up.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler("calendar",calendar_handler))
up.dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(inline_handler))

up.start_polling()
up.idle()
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы используете библиотеку pyTelegramBotAPI, а в коде - python-telegram-bot (https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot)
Чтобы этот код работал установите pip install python-telegram-bot